# Set German keyboard layout for 16 Bit applications

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-vista, keyboard-layout, 16-bit

When I run 16 Bit applications (such as QBASIC and edit.com) on Windows Vista or Windows 7, 16 Bit applications are using the keyboard layout of American keyboards. I want them to use the German keyboard layout. How is using the German keyboard layout possible?

Comment: 16 Bit applications can use different layouts by using a dos command chcp to change the codepage. I don't know what codepage you need to use for your german keyboard though.

Comment: You have to use kb16 in order to change the keyboard layout of 16 Bit applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command in a command prompt, which you use later to run the 16 Bit application:

```
kb16 gr
```

Gr stands for German.
If you want that the German keyboard is used for all 16 Bit applications on your Windows computer, follow these steps:

1. Click Start/All Programs/Accessories Right-Click on notepad.
2. Click on "Run as administrator". Confirm the prompt of the user account
   control.
3. Click on File/Open and open C:\Windows\System32\autoexec.nt .
4. Add the same line as above to the end of the file.
5. Click on File/Save.

The commands in autoexec.nt will always be executed, when a 16 Bit application is run. Therefore all 16 Bit applications will use the German keyboard layout.